# Why the array name argv can be assigned?

Tags: c, argv

As we know, array name can't be assigned, sentence like:

```
char * array[], * point;
array = point; /* wrong */
array++; /* wrong */
```

But in `main(int argc, char * argv[])`, `argv++` is ok and works well.
What do i missing?

Comment: I had no idea array parameters were degraded to pointers this way. Thanks for asking the question that brought it up!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[]` and `T a[N]` are both interpreted as `T *a`; in all three cases, `a` is declared as a *pointer* to `T`, not an array of `T`.  Thus,  in `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, `argv` is really declared as `char **`, or pointer to pointer to `char`, not array of pointer to `char`.

(**edit** -- note that this is true *only* for function parameter declarations; for a regular variable declaration, `T a[N]` and `T a[]` both declare `a` as an array of `T`).

Since it's a pointer value, it can be assigned to and it can be incremented.

Beyond that, here's what the [language standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) has to say:

> #### 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup
>
> ...
> 2 If they are declared, the parameters to the main function shall obey the following
> constraints:
> ...
> — The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the `argv` array shall
> be modiﬁable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program
> startup and program termination.

**EDIT**

And here's the language for function parameters:

> #### 6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)
>
> ...
> 7 A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of *type*’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualiﬁed pointer to
> *type*’’, where the type qualiﬁers (if any) are those speciﬁed within the `[` and `]` of the
> array type derivation. If the keyword `static` also appears within the `[` and `]` of the
> array type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the corresponding
> actual argument shall provide access to the ﬁrst element of an array with at least as many
> elements as speciﬁed by the size expression.

**EDIT<sup>2</sup>**

Some examples (assumes a C99 compiler):

```
void foo(int a[], size_t len)
{
  size_t i;
  printf("sizeof a = %zu\n", sizeof a);
  printf("sizeof (int *) = %zu\n", sizeof (int *));
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    printf("a[%zu] = %d\n", i, *a++);
}

int main(void)
{
  int a1[5] = {0};
  int a2[]  = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

  printf("sizeof a1 = %zu\n", sizeof a1);
  printf("sizeof a2 = %zu\n", sizeof a2);

  foo(a1, sizeof a1 / sizeof a1[0]);
  foo(a2, sizeof a2 / sizeof a2[0]);

  return 0;
}
```

One more piece of standardese:

> #### 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators
>
> ...
> 3 Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
>  unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
> type ‘‘array of *type*’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to *type*’’ that points
>                to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has
>               register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

In the function `main`, `a1` and `a2` have been declared as 5-element arrays of `int`; `a2` gets its size from the number of elements in the initializer.  The *expressions* `a1` and `a2` thus have types "5-element array of `int`" and they may not be targets of an assignment expression, nor may they be operands to the `++` or `--` operators.  When these expressions appear in the call to `foo`, their types are converted to "pointer to `int`" per the rule above.  Thus `foo` receives a pointer value, not an array value, for `a` (which is covered by the rule that says array parameters are converted to pointer types).  So the expression `a` in `foo` has type `int *`, or pointer to `int`; thus, `a` may be the target of an assignment, and it may be an operand of `++` and `--`.

One more difference: per the rule quoted above, the conversion to a pointer type *doesn't* happen when the array expression is an operand of the `sizeof` operator; `sizeof a1` should evaluate to the number of bytes taken up by the array `a1` (5 * sizeof `int`).  However, since `a` in `foo` has type `int *`, not `int [5]`, `sizeof a` should only evaluate to the number of bytes for an pointer to `int` (sizeof `(int *)`).

Comment: I still don't know in which case, the array type derivation would get the actual type, can you give a example?

Answer (score 6):

In your examples `array` is a true array, and thus a non-modifiable l-value. In main, since it's declared in the parameter list, `argv` is actually a `char **`, i.e. a pointer which is modifiable.

It all boils down to the fact that `char *array[]` means different things, depending on the context.

Answer (score 2):

```
main(int argc, char * argv[])
```

or

```
main(int argc, char **argv)
```

are same and correct .Because in function arguments array are decayed into pointers

For more [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

But the code you have shown is the actual array . And name of the array gives the address of the first element and it's non modifiable that's why doing this :

```
 array = point; 
array++;
```

is wrong as you have already mentioned it.

Comment: Decaying of array explains. BTW, The `void by_reference(const T (&array)[U])` in the url you given is said can give proper sizeof() info, but when i test it in my code, I got a error. Why?

Comment: It's the pass by reference which is in C++ not in C.And remember reference is just an alias of the same variable.